# CSS - How can I push the submenus to the left?

Tags: html, css, submenu

I have created a horizontal menu with a horizontal submenu. Though I want all the submenus to be pushed to the left, just like the first submenu. How can I do that? I'm very (very) new to CSS.

I have this HTML code:

```
<div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#nogo">Link 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#nogo">Link 1-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#nogo">Link 1-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#nogo">Link 1-3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#nogo">Link 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#nogo">Link 2-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#nogo">Link 2-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#nogo">Link 2-3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#nogo">Link 3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#nogo">Link 3-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#nogo">Link 3-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#nogo">Link 3-3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

And I have this CSS code:

```
    #menu{
padding:0;
margin:0;
overflow:hidden;
height:60px;
}
#menu ul{
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
#menu li{
position: relative;
float: left;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding:0;
}

#menu li a{
width:100px;
height: 30px;
display: block;
text-decoration:none;
text-align: center;
line-height: 30px;
background-color: black;
color: white;
}

#menu li a:hover{
background-color: red;
}

#menu ul ul{
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
visibility: hidden;
width: 600px;
}

#menu ul li:hover ul{
visibility:visible;
display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `position: relative` from `#menu li` and add it to `#menu ul` instead. Also add `left: 0` to `#menu ul ul`:

```css
#menu ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative; /* add this */
}

#menu li {
  /* position: relative;   //remove this */
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; /* add this */
  top: 30px;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 600px;
}
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/WJN4G/**

Answer (score 1):

move the positioning from `#menu li` to `#menu ul` and add `left:0;` to `#menu ul ul`

The `left:0;` causes the element (`#menu ul ul`) to be aligned with it's first parent having a position other then `static` (which is the default). That's why you need to move the `position:relative` on element up to the `#menu ul`, so all the child `ul` align to the left edge of the parent `ul`.

```css
#menu ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative; /* <- moved */
}

#menu li {
  position: relative; /* <- deleted */
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; /* <- added */
  top: 30px;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 600px;
}
```

here is your modified **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/Z7Y2P/)**

Comment: dunno what you are talking about?

Comment: Don't worry about it, it was just some light humour :: *Jinx - A penalty that one person can invoke on another when the two of them say the same thing at the same time.* [Wikipedia - Jinx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinx)